# Best practices for handling pytest failed assertions

Tags: pyspark, pytest, amazon-emr

I am using pyspark, EMR, terraform and airflow for triggering. I am writing pytest cases in my pyspark code. I have the following questions:

I)If I get an assertion as "False". I am thinking of sending a slack and email notification and shut down EMR cluster. is this the best practice that everyone follows? .

Can someone explain how to handle pytests in cases of failure assertions? or general methods of handling pytest failures

Sample code:

```
def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    SLACK_CONN_ID = 'slack'
    slack_webhook_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    slack_msg = """
            :red_circle: crunchbase Job Failed.
            *Task*: {task}
            *Dag*: {dag}
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}
            *Log Url*: {log_url}
            *Error*:{exception}
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
            exception=context.get('exception')

        )
    failed_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack',
        http_conn_id='slack',
        webhook_token=slack_webhook_token,
        message=slack_msg,
        username='airflow_sld',
        dag=dag)
    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)
```

Comment: *Best practices* questions are not appropriate here. Please see [Is a best practices question off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265928/62576) and revise your question so that it is more acceptable here.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to post questions of this kind?

Comment: You can ask that question at [meta.se]. Ask where to post it, include the body of your post as a blockquote, and someone there can guide you to the proper site. But you should consider reading the post I linked and then making an edit to your post here to restate the problem, because this is probably the proper site if you ask the correct question.,

Comment: @Nilesh: Yes I have got it, please see added sample code

Comment: @Nilesh: You need to add SLACK_CONN_ID in connection tab airflow

Comment: @Xi12 is this `task_fail_slack_alert` tirgger automatically ? like pytest know when test fail, then call this function ?

Comment: yes you need to create slack webhook and add conection